# Can prevent "LOCAL SERVICE" from changing the system time?

Tags: security, operating-system

I posted a question because I needed help.

**Security Settings (secpol.msc) - Local Policy - User Rights Assignment - Change the system time**

The default member of the above item is "Administrators, LOCAL SERVICE".

I deleted "LOCAL SERVICE" from the "Change the system time" item according to the work instruction, but it was restored again.

Is there a way to enable deletion or prevent "LOCAL SERVICE" from changing the system time?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"NT AUTHORITY" or "NT SERVICE/LOCAL SERVICE" is a system builtin SID. Its capibility cannot be disabled by user but hard-coded in kernel. Try to add a new user to limit a "more danger service" or simply create virtual service account(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd548356(v=ws.10))